# Sending certificate with future timestamp

Tags: java, date, certificate

Suppose two people run the same code and the first one creates a certificate with createDate and expireDate and a file is valid if

createDate < currentTimeOfTheUserComputer < expireDate .

Now if the first person sends this certificate(suppose for him it is valid) to someone else who is 8 hours behind around the world ,for the second person it will be invalid.In such a scenario how is this problem resolved or is there a policy how it should be if we want the second person to be able to use it without waiting 8 hours?

Comment: You might want to watch [The Problem with Time and Timezones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)

Comment: If the program uses UTC time, then no-one is 8 hours behind.

Comment: Do you think the implementers of certificates could possibly have not considered these issues?  Certificates use UTC internally.  There is no issue with time zones.  If by "certificate" you are referring to some custom private object your software creates, if it does not use UTC internally then it must be modified to use UTC or face these issues.

Comment: Wonderful instructive 10 minutes video, @agillgilla

Comment: I was being genuine, @agillgilla. If the asker’s certificates use UTC, it may not be terribly relevant here, but I certainly think he’s packed a lot of good points that a lot of programmers should know about into a not too long and also entertaining video. I genuinely like it.

Answer (score 0):

RFC 5280, which handles X.509 certificates specifies two methods to encode validity times in certificates:

- UTCTime
- GeneralizedTime

Both rely on the GMT zone as reference. If both implementations use the correct time zone for generation and checking, your scenario should not present a problem.

See [RFC 5280 on validity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280.html#section-4.1.2.5)

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't realize that `Date` always uses UTC Time.  So any time you want to get the date, you access it like this:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class CurrentDateTime {
    public static String getCurrDateTime() {
        Date date = new Date();
        return date;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DateCertificate {
    public static void createCertificate() {
        Date createDate = CurrentDateTime.getCurrDateTime();
        /* Save createDate to file or something */
    }

    public static boolean certificateValid() {
        Date currentDate = CurrentDateTime.getCurrDateTime();
        /* Get createDate and expireDate from file or something */
        return currentDate.after(createDate) && currentDate.before(expireDate);
    }
}
```

You can use `getCurrDateTime()` and some other `Date` methods to get the `createDate` and `expireDate` and save them to a file or however you want to store them, then use the `certificateValid()` method to check if the `currentDate` is between the two.

Thanks Jim for pointing out my mistake.

**Note:** This could be easily spoofed/tricked because it is dependent on the time reading from the client machine that is given to the JVM.  So **do not** use this for free trial validation or the like.

Comment: Anyone who downvoted care to explain what's wrong with my post?